# How to return time in integer method? (C#)

Tags: c#

Using the C# language, have the function StringChallenge(num) take the num

- parameter being passed and return the number of hours and minutes the parameter     *
- converts to (ie. if num = 63 then the output should be 1:3). Separate the number    *
- of hours and minutes with a colon.

The question above. Problem is how to convert time with colon as return in integer function?

```
  using System;    
  class MainClass {
  
      
  public static int StringChallenge(int num) {
      
  // code goes here  
  int hour=0;
  int min=0;
  if (num<60)
  {
    
    min = num;
     }
  if (num>60)
  {
    min = num % 60;
    hour = num / 60;
   
  }
  
  return num ;
  
    }
  
    static void Main() {  
      // keep this function call here
      Console.WriteLine(StringChallenge(Console.ReadLine()));
    } 
  
  }
```

Comment: can you give an example to the format you want??

Comment: consider using a `TimeSpan` instead

Comment: numbers don't have a colon in them.

Comment: if number = 58 it should return 0:58

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to return an `int`, and not a `string`?

Comment: There is no way you can return `0:58` as an int. It is simply not possible. Either you misunderstood the task, or the person that wrote it doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: For context, it might help if you share a link to the page on coderbyte you referred to.

Comment: I think the same thing. There must be a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string interpolation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {

  public static string StringChallenge(int num) {
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    // code goes here  
    int hour=0;
    int min=0 ;
    if (num<60)
    {
      
      min = num;
       }
    if (num>60)
    {
      min = num % 60;
      hour = num / 60;
     
    }

    return $"{hour} : {min}";

  }

  static void Main() {  
    // keep this function call here
    Console.WriteLine(StringChallenge(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
  } 

}
```

Comment: but function type is static int not static string and it don't allow me to change it as string.

Comment: how did you convert it to a string, the return for the method is a string.

Comment: Please make your code cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Let [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0) do the work for you:

```
int num = 60;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(num);
string formatted = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

which outputs a string like

> 01:00

To change the format, different patterns can be used. Check out the [documentation on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) if necessary.

Comment: But beware that `TimeSpan.FromDays(1.1).ToString(@"hh\:mm")` results in `02:24` when the correct span is 26 hours, 24 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have taken the method:

```
public static string StringChallenge(int minute)
{
    return $"{minute / 60}:{minute % 60}";
}
```

> from a 59 turns into "0:59"

> from a 60 turns into "1:0"

> from a 61 turns into"1:1"

Comment: @nogabemist If you found it helpful, do you like it Then mark it as "correct answer"? (is the check mark on the top left)

Answer (score 0):

In *general case*, I can see two problems here:

- **Large** `num`, say `num = 1600`, we want `26:40`, not `1 day 2:40`
- **Negative** numbers: we want `-12:30`, not `-12:30`

**Code**

```
// Note, that we should return string, not int
// d2 - formatting - to have leading zeroes, i.e. 5:01 instead of 5:1
public static string StringChallenge(int num) =>
  $"{num / 60}:{Math.Abs(num % 60):d2}";
```